# Numpy 3D array to 2D row major array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with dimensions (28, 28, 60000), containing 60000 28x28 images, represented as pixel brightness. I'm trying to transform it so that I have a 60000 x 784 array, with the 784 representing the original 28x28 image in row major format. How do I do this? I'm assuming I use numpy.reshape, but I'm unsure as to how it rearranges things. Example:

```
[[1,2],        [[1,2,3,4],
 [3,4]]         [5,6,7,8]]
...       -> 
[[5,6],
 [7,8]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
print(numpy.reshape(a, (2,4)))
```

Returns:

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to experiment with something like this:

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape((3, 2))
b = np.reshape(a, (1, 6))
print a
print b
a = 
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]]
b = [[0 1 2 3 4 5]]
```